How can I associate, group, or connect rows in Excel?
This might be a niche question so I'll try to generalize it as much as possible.
Upon extracting data from a folder with PDF files and after some data cleaning, I have the following in PowerQuery:



Date
Values




01.01.2024




values for day 01.01...


02.01.2024




values for 02.01...


05.01.2024




values for 05.01...


04.01.2024




values for 04.01...



more values for 04.01...


03.01.2024




values for 03.01...



Some observations:

if a cell in the Date column is populated, it is always with a date, and the cell in the column Values is empty.
Correspondingly, if a cell in Values is populated, then the cell to the left is empty.
The number of values for each day is irregular. In reality most dates have at least three corresponding values in the Values column.
each date from 01.01 to 31.01 appears once and only once in the whole table.

The issue: some of the dates and their respective values are scattered throughout the table instead of being in order from oldest to most recent date. See for example dates 04.01.2024 and 05.01.2024 and their corresponding values.
The table should be looking like this instead:



Date
Values




01.01.2024




values for day 01.01...


02.02.2024




values for 02.01...


03.01.2024




values for 03.01...


04.01.2024




values for 04.01...



more values for 04.01...


05.01.2024




values for 05.01...



My question: How can I sort the Date column by ascending order, in a way that the rows with the values that correspond to their respective dates are "taken along" with the dates rows up and down the table?
I'm hoping that the scattered values having their correct date "near them" will help, so I'm wondering if there's a function that goes along something the lines of "if the dates being compared have the same value, take all values of the Values column of the second date until the first empty row next to the first instance of the date row...". Or maybe better, PowerQuery or Excel already have a feature like that implemented?
I first attempted to solve this by batch-editing the file names so that they would be loaded to PowerQuery already in the appropriate order, however I'd not taken into account that the file names don't always necessarily correspond to their correct order in the table, and the sample folder I was working with just coincidentally was one of the few instances where that would be enough to get the desired results.


Fill Down the dates
Group by Dates with no aggregation
Sort the Dates column
Expand the grouped table Value column.
Blank the Dates unless they are on the same row as a null entry for values

The last step must be done by manually entering M-code into the advanced editor. The other steps can be done from the User Interface
M Code
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Values", type text}}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Changed Type",{"Date"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Date"}, {{"all", each _, type table [Date=nullable date, Values=nullable text]}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Expanded all" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "all", {"Values"}),

//Replace dates with null unless Value emapty
    #"Replace Dates" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Expanded all",
        each [Values],
        null,
        (x,y,z) as nullable date=> if y = null then x else z,
        {"Date"}
    )
in
    #"Replace Dates"



This would be doable using a formula as well:
=LET(a,A2:B12,SORTBY(IF(a="","",a),SCAN(,TAKE(a,,1),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(LEN(b),b,a)))))

SCAN is used to fill the gaps in the date column with it's preceding value. Than the range is sorted by that.

Perfect with SCAN()
